# Android Client Connecting to Jersey Rest - Post gives 405

Tags: android, rest, jersey

Im writing an android app that connects to my own Jersey rest client. HTTP get commands work fine, but im having trouble with my POSTs where im trying to send something to the server. I get a 405 sent back, so it seems like the server cannot match the request up with the resource methods. Any thoughts? Test code below...

REST SERVER

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MultiPartMediaTypes.MULTIPART_MIXED)
public Response putResponse(MultiPart multiPart) {
    System.out.println(multiPart.getBodyParts());
    return null;
}
```

ANDROID CLIENT

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL + "responses");
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("Testpart1", new StringBody("<testxml></testxml>"));
entity.addPart("image1", new StringBody("imagedata1"));
request.setEntity(entity);
request.addHeader("deviceId", deviceId);
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
try {
    String result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
    Log.i("tag", result);
return result;
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
return null;
```

TCPMon Traffic shows the following
    POST /Maintenance_Server/rest/responses HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed
    deviceId: xxxxx
    Content-Length: 244
    Host: 127.0.0.1:12345
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

```
--jju2JFDOlzJ4LQo7YkrJYLuwDUHmB5b7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Testpart1"

<testxml></testxml>
--jju2JFDOlzJ4LQo7YkrJYLuwDUHmB5b7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"

imagedata1
--jju2JFDOlzJ4LQo7YkrJYLuwDUHmB5b7--
```

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending HTTP POST, but on the server side you declare a handler for HTTP PUT only. So, it's not able to match POST to any method hence 405. Change the annotation on your resource method from @PUT to @POST or send HTTP PUT instead of POST by the client.

Comment: Couldnt see that problem for looking. Thanks for the second pair of eyes.